# pasar información de inputs a modal es javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

quiero mostrar la información de los inputs y selects que se van a registrar en un modal ya creado para previsualizar la información que esta pronta agudarse.

muestro imagen de mis formularios dinámicos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

muestro parte del código de dichos formularios:

### Formato de Velada

```
      </div><div class="previews result2">

     <input type="text" id="letra2" class="login-input" name="fecha" required 
       placeholder="Fecha" autocomplete="off">
      </div><div class="previews">
        <select name="autorizo" id="letra2" class="login-input" 
         required>option

    <option disabled selected value="">Autorizo</option>
    <?php
     $rows3=$optionsmodel->getAutorizo(); 
      foreach ($rows3 as $row) {                               
      ?>  
     <option value="<?= $row['Nombre'];?>"><?= $row['Nombre'];?> </option>
     <?php 
      }
      ?>

    </select>
      </div><div class="previews">
        <select id="letra2" name="responsable_velada" value="responsable" 
    class="login-input" required>

    <option disabled selected value="">Responsable:</option>
      <?php
     $rows4=$optionsmodel->getPersonal(); 
      foreach ($rows4 as $row) {                               
     ?>  
     <option><?php echo $row['usuario'];?> </option>
     <?php 
     }
      ?>

   </select>
      </div><div class="previews result3">
        <button type="submit" id="btn1" name="insertar" class="cotizador- 
        button blue2" "="">Guardar</button>
      </div>

    </div>
```

muestro imagen de lo que quiero hacer con valores predeterminados aun no es funcional:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

debiera de quedar de esa forma al dar si procede con la inserción al dar no re regresa (la es funcional eso) pero los datos nose como enviarlos de los inputs al  modal para que me muestre la información
codigo jq:

```
      $(document).on("submit","#form-velada",function(e){
e.preventDefault();

$('.cotizador_box').animate({'opacity':'1'}, 300, 'linear');
$('.backdrop').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
$('.backdrop, .cotizador_box').css('display', 'block');

var html='<p><span>Fecha:</span> <?php echo $Fecha?> <p>';
html+='<p><span>Autorizo:</span><p>';
html+='<p><span>Responsable:</span> Fernando Fernandez<p><br>';
html+='<p><span>Personal:</span><p>';
html+='<p class="p-list">-Eduardo, Encuadernacion</p>';
html+='<p class="p-list">-Naomi, Acabado</p>';
html+='<p class="p-list">-Martin, Taller</p>';
html+='<p><span>Ordenes:</span><p>';
html+='<p class="p-list">-QWE34, Esquela</p>';
html+='<p class="p-list">-GDDE45, Mapa</p>';
html+='<p class="p-list">-FDEE34, Sobre</p>';
html+='<p><span>Gastos:</span><p>';
html+='<p class="p-list">-Comida, $56</p>';
html+='<p class="p-list">-Transporte, cvxc$456</p>';
html+='<p class="p-list">-Otros, $345</p>';
$('#resumen').append(html);


    }); 

  $(document).on("click","#cancelar",function(e){
  closeModal();
});
  $(document).on("click","#guardar",function(e){
  $('.cotizador_box').hide();
$('.loader').show();
 $.ajax({
```

codigo completo del modal:

```
      <div class="modal-close"></div>
      <h2>¿Todos los datos son correctos?</h2>
       <div  id="resumen">

       </div>
       <button class="tab-btn-sumbit" id="guardar">Si</button><button 
        class="tab-btn-cancel" id="cancelar">No</button>
        </div>
        <div class="loader">
       <img src="<?php echo URL; ?>public/img/whloader.gif">
       </div>

       <div class="backdrop"></div>



          <script>

      $(function(){




    $("#adicional2").on('click', function(){

      var row='<tr><td><select name="area[]" class="login-input" id="letra2" 
       required><option disabled selected value="">Area de trabajo:</option> 
       <option value="maquinas">Maquinas</option><option 
       value="encuadernacion">Encuadernacion</option><option 
       value="acabado">Acabado</option></select></td><td><select 
       name="personal[]" class="login-input" required ><option disabled 
       selected value="">Nombre del trabajador:</option><?=$options_nombre ?> 
       </select></td><td class="eliminar"><div class="table-button 
        orange2">Quitar</div></td>';

      $("#tabla2").append(row);

       });
      $("#adicional3").on('click', function(){

      var row= '<tr><td><input required type="text" class="login-input"  
        name="clave[]" placeholder="ODT"/></td><td><input required 
       type="text" placeholder="Ingrese decripcion" class="login-input" 
      name="descripcion[]"/></td><td class="eliminar"><div class="table- 
       button orange2">Quitar</div></td></tr>';



      $("#tabla3").append(row);


    });
    $("#adicional4").on('click', function(){ 

    var row='<tr><td><select  name="tipo_gasto[]" class="login-input" 
     required><option disabled selected value="">Gastos velada:</option> 
    <option value="Transporte">Tansporte</option><option 
    value="Alimentos">Alimentos</option><option value="Otros gastos">Otros 
    gastos</option></select></td><td><input required type="number" 
    class="login-input" step="any" name="costo[]" placeholder="Ingrese 
    Costo"/></td><td class="eliminar"><div class="table-button 
     orange2">Quitar</div></td></tr>';
      $("#tabla4").append(row);

    });

    $(document).on("click",".eliminar",function(){
    var parent = $(this).parents().get(0);
    $(parent).remove();
    });
     });  

    (function($) {  

        $(function(){
               jQuery214( "#letra2" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm- 
          yy',onSelect: function() {
         $(this).change();
        } });

          })
         })(jQuery);

          (function($){
      $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
      closeText: 'Cerrar',
       prevText: '&#x3c;Ant',
        nextText: 'Sig&#x3e;',
      currentText: 'Hoy',
       monthNames: ['Enero','Febrero','Marzo','Abril','Mayo','Junio',
      'Julio','Agosto','Septiembre','Octubre','Noviembre','Diciembre'],
     monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr','May','Jun',
       'Jul','Ago','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dic'],
    dayNames: ['Domingo','Lunes','Martes','Mi&eacute;rcoles','Jueves','Viernes','S&aacute;bado'],
dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mi&eacute;','Juv','Vie','S&aacute;b'],
dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','S&aacute;'],
weekHeader: 'Sm',
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
firstDay: 1,
isRTL: false,
showMonthAfterYear: false,
yearSuffix: ''};
  $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);
       })(jQuery214);

      $(document).on("click",".modal-close",function(e){
       closeModal();
        });  
        $(document).on("submit","#form-velada",function(e){
             e.preventDefault();

          $('.cotizador_box').animate({'opacity':'1'}, 300, 'linear');
          $('.backdrop').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
        $('.backdrop, .cotizador_box').css('display', 'block');

var html='<p><span>Fecha:</span> <?php echo $Fecha?> <p>';
html+='<p><span>Autorizo:</span><p>';
html+='<p><span>Responsable:</span> Fernando Fernandez<p><br>';
html+='<p><span>Personal:</span><p>';
html+='<p class="p-list">-Eduardo, Encuadernacion</p>';
html+='<p class="p-list">-Naomi, Acabado</p>';
html+='<p class="p-list">-Martin, Taller</p>';
html+='<p><span>Ordenes:</span><p>';
html+='<p class="p-list">-QWE34, Esquela</p>';
html+='<p class="p-list">-GDDE45, Mapa</p>';
html+='<p class="p-list">-FDEE34, Sobre</p>';
html+='<p><span>Gastos:</span><p>';
html+='<p class="p-list">-Comida, $56</p>';
html+='<p class="p-list">-Transporte, cvxc$456</p>';
html+='<p class="p-list">-Otros, $345</p>';
$('#resumen').append(html);


          }); 

        $(document).on("click","#cancelar",function(e){
                                        closeModal();
                });
          $(document).on("click","#guardar",function(e){
          $('.cotizador_box').hide();
         $('.loader').show();
        $.ajax({  
       type:"POST",
       url:"<?=URL?>velada/Guardar",   
      data:$('#form-velada').serialize(),
      dataType:"json",   
      success:function(data){ 
       closeModal();
       $('#messages').html(data.message);
       $('#resumen').html('');
       }  
       });
       });
        function closeModal(){

      $('.backdrop, .cotizador_box, .loader').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 300, 
       'linear', function(){
      $('.backdrop, .cotizador_box, .loader').css('display', 'none');
       });  

       }
     < /script>
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar tu HTML del modal, también darte a explicar mejor, se ve que escribiste a las prisas y no te diste el tiempo de explicar y terminar hasta oraciones, sería más fácil el poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tus datos estén dentro del formulario llamado "form1" quedaría algo así:

```
 $(document).on("submit","#form-velada",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.cotizador_box').animate({'opacity':'1'}, 300, 'linear');
    $('.backdrop').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
    $('.backdrop, .cotizador_box').css('display', 'block');

var letra1 = $("#form1 #letra1").val();
var letra2 = $("#form1 #letra2").val();
// y así los demás campos
// Ya solo resta mostrarlos en una cadena:
var html = "Dato1: "+letra1+" - Dato2: "+letra2;
```

Comment: letra es un value o id del input? y form1 es el valor del form?

Comment: form1 es el id de tu formulario y letra1 y letra2 son valores de tus inputs que tienes en el código que pusiste.